# HTC Vive / Oculus Rift with MacBook

Tags: macos, htc-vive

Could someone please help me understand if HTC Vive works with MacOS? I have a macbook and am learning VR. I need to purchase one of the devices - either HTC Vive or Oculus Rift. Although the websites for both Oculus and Vive have mentioned that these work with Windows, but I have seen HTC Vive image on VR slides from Apple in WWDC. So, just thought of confirming this.

Any idea?

Regards,
Kavita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently bought the HTC Vive and it works with MacOS, equipped with Radeon Pro graphic Card. High Sierra has already all drivers implemented. For a macBookPro it seems though that you will need an external graphic Card.

Comment: Thanks for confirmin. I am able to run Vive with MacOS.